# Cross-Platform CocosSharp Content Pipeline Project?

Tags: monogame

Just getting started with CocosSharp and Xamarin.Forms and I wanted to move on from using Circles and lines to draw everything. It looks like setting up a MonoGame Content Pipeline project is the way to go.

I've got the tool installed (on my mac). My "game" is actually really simple and is more of a visualization. I want to load up a texture file for a background, an image or two for the foreground, and a largish pile of sound files.

Do I have to manage the exact same files twice, in a separate tool from Xamarin Studio in order to do this? It seems like I'm missing something, but the documentation doesn't talk about cross-platform sharing at all.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the content project MSBuild overrides the set platform in your project (using it only as a default when you're building in the tool itself). You can use a single project, referencing it from both your platform specific tools to make sure MSBuild does this correctly.

Found the answer in a blog post by @darkside:

> [The project's] platform is determined when you build the project You
>   can either fix the platform build type (which is like setting a
>   default) and build the content manually (you can also call the MGCB
>   tool programmatically from a build script to build it separately if
>   you wish as well, for advanced users). Alternatively, if you have your
>   content file attached to your solution (which is the default), then
>   Visual Studio will tell the Content Project which platform to build
>   based on the platform you are building automatically, regardless of
>   whether you share the project or not.  This means you don't have to
>   worry if the content will work on the platform or not (as different
>   platforms use different methods for compression, formatting and so on.
>   An XNB file built for Windows likely won't work on Android for
>   example.

Quote from: http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/monogame-building-multi-platform-solutions/